# Set Animation for Custom TextView

Tags: animation, mvvm, mvvmcross

I have a custom TextView and I want to set an Animation for when the textview comes into view (I have bound its visibility to a property).  I know about setting the animation OnClick but I cannot use that because I am using MvvmCross and an MvVM design.

```
public class AnimatedTextView : TextView
    {
        protected AnimatedTextView(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer)
        {            
        }

        public AnimatedTextView(Context context) : base(context)
        {
            Typeface tf = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(context.Assets, "Fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf");
            SetTypeface(tf, TypefaceStyle.Normal);
            var spinInAnim = AnimationUtils.LoadAnimation(context, Resource.Animation.spinInAnimation);
            Animation = spinInAnim;
        }

        public AnimatedTextView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs)
        {
            Typeface tf = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(context.Assets, "Fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf");
            SetTypeface(tf, TypefaceStyle.Normal);
            var spinInAnim = AnimationUtils.LoadAnimation(context, Resource.Animation.spinOutAnimation);
            Animation = spinInAnim;
        }

        public AnimatedTextView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) : base(context, attrs, defStyle)
        {
            Typeface tf = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(context.Assets, "Fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf");
            SetTypeface(tf, TypefaceStyle.Normal);
            var spinInAnim = AnimationUtils.LoadAnimation(context, Resource.Animation.spinOutAnimation);
            Animation = spinInAnim;
        }
    }
```

I thought setting the animation would do the trick but apparently not. Any suggestions?

Comment: mvvm != no codebehind **or** cram-your-UI-code-into-viewmodels. UI concerns go in the UI.

Comment: Yes, I understand that.  I could have written the logic in the code behind but I am using data binding with MvvmCross, so if write the logic there I lose my binding, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: "but I am using data binding with MvvmCross" okay, that's nice. Apply the animation in your codebehind.